# How to access elements of array when parameter is double pointer?

Tags: c

First function changes big letter to small. In main I need to have five strings and with function `konvertuj` I have to go through that array and check for each letter if it's big and convert it to small. The point is that I don't know how to access each character of string in the function. (It's study example so it has to be done with these predefined functions.

```
char v2m(char z){
        char m = z + 0x20;
        return m;
    }
    void konvertuj(char **niz, int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if(*niz[i] > 'A' && *niz[i] < 'Z')
            *niz[i] = v2m(*niz[i]);
    }
    int main(){
        char **niz;
        niz[0] = "Voda";
        niz[1] = "KraISSa";
        niz[2] = "somsssR";
        niz[3] = "aaaaa";
        niz[4] = "WeWeWeW";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int d = -1;
            while(niz[i][++d]);
            konvertuj(&niz[i], d);
            printf("%s ", niz[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The variable `niz` is a pointer, but you never make it point anywhere. Therefore any dereference of it (like you do with e.g. `niz[0]`) will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And what is the reason you pass a pointer to a pointer to the `konvertuj` function? That makes no sense, just pass a plain `char *`. I also recommend you use the [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) and [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) functions instead of making these parts yourself (especially the "is upper-case letter" part in your code is not portable).

Comment: It's school assignment and they want us to work without those functions atm. As I said, it's predefined function and we have to make the rest. Can someone fix this code?

Comment: The `konvertuj` function doesn't make sense because `*niz[i]` is the first (zeroth) character of the `i`th string. It would make more sense if it used `(*niz)[i]` which is the `i`th character of the first (zeroth, and only) string. It would be even better to use a `char *niz` parameter instead of `char **niz`, but apparently you have been forbidden to do that.

Comment: I added code below to show you one way to write this using `char**` as you tried to,  and another way  using standard `char[][]`. And also I wrote about some mistakes in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `v2m` - no need of the variable `m`
2. `konvertuj` no need to iterate through the same letters all over again. You want to convert 1 letter as you iterate in `main`. Your condition is wrong as you will ignore `'A'` and `'Z'`
3. Pointer to pointer does not have allocated space to accommodate 5 pointers. You need to allocate this space. In your code is it UB.

3.a You assign the pointers to the string literals. Attempt to modify the string literal invokes Undefined Behaviour. In my code, I use compound literals which are modifiable.

3.b use correct type for indexes (`size_t`).

```
char v2m(char z){
    return z + 0x20;
}
void konvertuj(char *niz, size_t n){
    if(niz[n] >= 'A' && niz[n] <= 'Z')
        niz[n] = v2m(niz[n]);
}

int main(void){
    char **niz = malloc(5 * sizeof((*niz)));
    niz[0] = (char[]){"Voda"};
    niz[1] = (char[]){"KraISSa"};
    niz[2] = (char[]){"somsssR"};
    niz[3] = (char[]){"aaaaa"};
    niz[4] = (char[]){"WeWeWeW"};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        size_t d = 0;
        while(niz[i][d])
            konvertuj(niz[i], d++);
        printf("%s ", niz[i]);
    }
}
```

As I( understand you need to keep the function names types and parameters

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible to write it the way you did, but you have to build things accordingly and you did not.

And there some errors, anyway. I will try to show you some points. Please be patient.

```
        niz[0] = "Voda";
        niz[1] = "KraISSa";
        niz[2] = "somsssR";
        niz[3] = "aaaaa";
        niz[4] = "WeWeWeW";
```

In C in general you can not just assign a value to a string. You use something like

```
    strcpy( niz[0], "ANewValue");
```

#### v2m()

Instead of

```
    char v2m(char z){
        char m = z + 0x20;
        return m;
    }
```

You can just write

```
    char v2m(char z) { return z + 0x20; }
```

There is no need to declare a char just for holding the return value.
IIUC you can not change the function prototypes...

#### konvertuj()

```
    void konvertuj(char **niz, int n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if(*niz[i] > 'A' && *niz[i] < 'Z')
            *niz[i] = v2m(*niz[i]);
    }
```

here I believe you missed the point that the function will receive just a string each time is called, not the whole vector of strings.
The `int n` is just the length of the string, and even if you could not use `strlen()` to compute it, it should probably be done *inside* the function.
but I believe you can not change this prototype also.

- note that you are not including 'A' and 'Z' in your test. Maybe you should use '>=' and '<=' in the tests.
- since the function gets a single string each call, you must remove many of the  '*'
- note that you had the strings declared as literals, CONSTANTS that you can not change. The first time you try to change a letter your program will abort

This one below should work and you can compare:

```
void konvertuj(char *niz, int n)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if(niz[i] >= 'A' && niz[i] <= 'Z')
                niz[i] = v2m(niz[i]);
}
```

#### main()

Instead of

```
        char **niz;
        niz[0] = "Voda";
        niz[1] = "KraISSa";
        niz[2] = "somsssR";
        niz[3] = "aaaaa";
        niz[4] = "WeWeWeW";
```

You could write just

```
        char    niz[][15] = 
        {
            "Voda",
            "KraISSa",
            "somsssR",
            "aaaaa",
            "WeWeWeW"
        };
```

In C just the last dimension must be declared, e.g. the '15' above, since the compiler can determine here the other dimension. And this way you can initialize all of them directly. But in order to change one in the code you need to use a loop and replace letter by letter, or call

```
        strcpy( niz[0], "ANewValue");
```

Also you can initialize just a few of them, and even out of order, as in

```
        char    niz[8][15] = 
        {
            [2] = "somsssR",
            [3] = "aaaaa",
            [5] = "AomsssZ",
            [6] = "A",
            [0] = "Voda",
            [1] = "KraISSa",
            [4] = "WeWeWeW",
            [7] = ""
        };
```

and this is really handy.

#### Computing the number of strings

Note that you can compute the number of strings and even assign "TheLastValue" to the last one, by writing

```
        int n = sizeof(niz)/sizeof(niz[0]); // total of strings
        strcpy( niz[n-1], "TheLastValue"); // changes the last string
        printf("Total of %llu values\n", sizeof(niz)/sizeof(niz[0]));
```

#### What if `char** niz` is needed?

This is a really common paradigm in C and C++, and it is very useful. You may recall that the prototype for main() is

```
    int main( int argc, char** argc)
```

for every C program, so you can see how common it is.

Fact is that when you declare `niz` as `char**` you are declaring a single variable. What is niz? Well, it is a pointer to a pointer to a char.

- `niz` is `char**`
- `*niz` is `char*`
- `**niz` is a single `char`

But `niz` is a pointer and it is pointing to nowhere when declared. In your case you want `niz` pointing to not one but **FIVE** strings. And if you do nothing the program will abort the first time you try to use it...
You need to build this:
A string is a pointer to the first `char`, `char*`

- so `niz` needs to point to an area capable of holding 5 pointers to `char`
- What about the size of a pointer to `char`? That is easy: `sizeof(char*)`
- Then you need to make each `niz[x]` point to the required string.
- It will not happen by itself. You must build each and every one.

#### An example: building `char** sample` from `niz` as declared above

The code below builds `sample` as an array of pointers, pointing to the same strings declared and allocated for `niz[][]` above, and them prints them all

```
        // building an array of pointers to the strings in niz
        char**      sample = NULL; // ok, points to nothing
        unsigned    area = n * sizeof(char*); // n pointers to strings

        sample = (char**) malloc(area);
        for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
            sample[i] = niz[i];

        printf("\n=>\tPrinting the %d strings using the pointers\n", n );
            for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
                printf("%2d: '%s'\n", i, sample[i]);
```

Note that the strings already exists and we are just pointing to them. A new reference only.

#### A new example: building `char** copy` as a full copy of `niz`

It is very very important to see the difference here: `copy` points to an array of pointers, but each pointer points to a copy of the corresponding string declared in `niz` and referenced in the `sample` array.

```
        // building 'copy' as an array of pointers to the strings once in niz
        char**      copy = NULL; // ok, points to nothing
        copy =      (char**) malloc(area);
        for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
        {
            copy[i] = (char*) malloc( (1 + sizeof(niz[i])) * sizeof(char) );
            // large enough to hold it
            int j = 0; // copy each letter
            for ( ; niz[i][j] != 0; j+=1 ) copy[i][j] = niz[i][j];
            copy[i][j] = 0; // this terminates the string
        }

        printf("\n=>\tPrinting the %d copies using the pointers\n", n );
            for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
                printf("%2d: '%s'\n", i, copy[i]);
```

**Note:** it is in general not recommended to cast the pointers return by malloc() in C, as in  the lines

```
        copy =      (char**) malloc(area);
// or
        copy[i] = (char*) malloc( (1 + sizeof(niz[i])) * sizeof(char) );
```

I just do not care and prefer to write all them down explicitly, as a reminder to myself of what is what. Sure, in C++ you *must* declare this, but is is rare to allocate memory this way in C++ since C++11. Fell free to use whatever rule you see fit

#### A complete example

This is the output

```
PS C:\src\ifdef> gcc -o teste  -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c17 so210126.c
PS C:\src\ifdef> ./teste
Total of 8 values  
Before: Voda (4)   
After: voda        
Before: KraISSa (7)
After: kraissa     
Before: somsssR (7)
After: somsssr     
Before: aaaaa (5)  
After: aaaaa       
Before: WeWeWeW (7)
After: wewewew
Before: AomsssZ (7)
After: aomsssz
Before: A (1)
After: a
Before: TheLastValue (12)
After: thelastvalue

=>      Printing the 8 strings using the pointers
 0: 'voda'
 1: 'kraissa'
 2: 'somsssr'
 3: 'aaaaa'
 4: 'wewewew'
 5: 'aomsssz'
 6: 'a'
 7: 'thelastvalue'

=>      Printing the 8 copies using the pointers
 0: 'voda'
 1: 'kraissa'
 2: 'somsssr'
 3: 'aaaaa'
 4: 'wewewew'
 5: 'aomsssz'
 6: 'a'
 7: 'thelastvalue'
PS C:\src\ifdef>
```

I compiled just on gcc 10.2 on Windows.

This is the example code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char v2m(char z) { return z + 0x20; }

void konvertuj(char *niz, int n)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if(niz[i] >= 'A' && niz[i] <= 'Z')
                niz[i] = v2m(niz[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
        char    niz[8][15] = 
        {
            [2] = "somsssR",
            [3] = "aaaaa",
            [5] = "AomsssZ",
            [6] = "A",
            [0] = "Voda",
            [1] = "KraISSa",
            [4] = "WeWeWeW",
            [7] = ""
        };

        int n = sizeof(niz)/sizeof(niz[0]); // total of strings
        strcpy( niz[n-1], "TheLastValue"); // changes the last string
        printf("Total of %llu values\n", sizeof(niz)/sizeof(niz[0]));

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int d = 0;
            while ( niz[i][d] != 0) d+=1;
            printf("Before: %s (%d)\n", niz[i], d);
            konvertuj( niz[i], d );
            printf("After: %s\n", niz[i]);
        }

        // building an array of pointers to the strings in niz
        char**      sample = NULL; // ok, points to nothing
        unsigned    area = n * sizeof(char*); // n pointers to strings

        sample = (char**) malloc(area);
        for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
            sample[i] = niz[i];

        printf("\n=>\tPrinting the %d strings using the pointers\n", n );
            for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
                printf("%2d: '%s'\n", i, sample[i]);

        // building 'copy' as an array of pointers to the strings once in niz
        char**      copy = NULL; // ok, points to nothing
        copy =      (char**) malloc(area);
        for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
        {
            copy[i] = (char*) malloc( (1 + sizeof(niz[i])) * sizeof(char) ); // large enough to hold it
            int j = 0; // copy each letter
            for ( ; niz[i][j] != 0; j+=1 ) copy[i][j] = niz[i][j];
            copy[i][j] = 0; // this terminates the string
        }

        printf("\n=>\tPrinting the %d copies using the pointers\n", n );
            for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1)
                printf("%2d: '%s'\n", i, copy[i]);

        for( int i=0; i<n; i+=1) free(copy[i]); // destroy each string
        free(copy); // destroy the array;
        free(sample); // sample points to static memory...
                
        return 0;
}
```

> As for the very very long post: I wanted to leave an example of the
> solution plus an example of the steps involved in order to build a `char**` vector from
> existing strings **and** as an independend copy.

Comment: Answer albeit long very imprecise and erratic. First of all 2D array is not pointer to pointer. Because arrays decay to pointers it is very confusing topic for beginners (including you).

Comment: `copy =      (char**) malloc(area);` there is no need to cast result of malloc. It is considered as a bad practice

Comment: @0___________ there is no 2D array in C or C++. These languages are not FORTRAN. As you can see in the added code a pointer to a pointer is just that. You build the contents and consume it as your program needs to.  It is confusing even for beginners and because of this I provided (i) a simple solution (ii) code that builds an array of pointers in the 2 common scenarios. It is not erratic. Just run the code...

As for the cast I already wrote , I do not care: I always cast the return of malloc() as a reminder for myself. And I wrote this in advance for comments like yours :)